# How to convert an array of structs into multiple columns?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema:

```
root (original)
 |-- entries: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I flatten it?

```
root (derived)
 |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ...
```

where col1...n is [col1 from original] and value for col1...n is value from [col2 from original]

Example:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|entries                                     |
+--------------------------------------------+
|[[a1, 1], [a2, P], [a4, N]                  |
|[[a1, 1], [a2, O], [a3, F], [a4, 1], [a5, 1]|
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I want to create the next dataset:

```
+-------------------------+
| a1 | a2 | a3  | a4 | a5 |
+-------------------------+
| 1  | P  | null| N | null|
| 1  | O  | F   | 1 | 1   |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: You can use `explode`. df.withColumn("entries", explode("entries")).select("entries.*").show

Comment: explode will create 2 columns (col1, col2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `explode` and `pivot`, to do so, one needs to create a `row_id` first:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  Seq(("a1", "1"), ("a2", "P"), ("a4", "N")),
  Seq(("a1", "1"), ("a2", "O"), ("a3", "F"), ("a4", "1"), ("a5", "1"))
).toDF("arr")
  .select($"arr".cast("array<struct<col1:string,col2:string>>"))

df
  .withColumn("row_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .select($"row_id", explode($"arr"))
  .select($"row_id", $"col.*")
  .groupBy($"row_id").pivot($"col1").agg(first($"col2"))
  .drop($"row_id")
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+---+----+---+----+
| a1| a2|  a3| a4|  a5|
+---+---+----+---+----+
|  1|  P|null|  N|null|
|  1|  O|   F|  1|   1|
+---+---+----+---+----+
```